# GParted permission issues

Tags: linux

On newly updated/upgraded Pi 3 B

1. I can list (lsusb) the device - eternally connected/powered hard drive
2. GParted will not detect the same device.
3. I can access the device via File Manager
4. parted command will not run because "I am not superuser".

I would like to change/update a bunch of partitions on the drive.

**QUESTION HOW do I accomplish that?** - 
since GParted does not work and I cannot get parted to start.

Comment: After weeks of frustration it turned  out as BAD USB cable between Pi and the common USB access. PC never failed to detect D-link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gparted requires root privileges to operate. You can become the root user by entering the following at the command line:

```
sudo su
```

**Note: you should not maintain the elevated privileges associated with the root account. Doing so is a security issue.**

to return to your regular user account, use the following:

```
exit
```

You can verify which user you are currently operating as with the following command:

```
whoami
```

The prompt on most systems will also change to indicate which user account you are using. It will normally show the username (i.e. root or pi) and when operating as the root user the prompt will end with a **#** rather than a **$**.

Comment: Sorry, per last site managerial  comment I cannot acknowledge or comment on you post. Thanks.